# Elementary Functions Name: f(a,b) = f(b,a-1)+b

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I am quite simply looking for a function that I forgot about from way back when. I am positive I learned this at some point in grade school, but I just can't remember what it is called!

The function in question is:

```
 if a = 0: f(a,b) = 0
 if a ≠ 0: f(a,b) = f(b,a – 1) + b
```

I am hoping that someone can remember what this is called! Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I am providing the simple code that I came up with that runs in Python. It does seem to be multiplication:

```
 def f(a,b,string):
     if (a==0):
         print (string)
         return 0
     if (a!=0):
         string += ( " + "+str(b) )
         return (f(b,a-1,string)+b)
```

**NEXT QUESTION:**
Is there a proof for this anywhere?

Comment: Multiplication?

Comment: With f(7,5), I return did return 35. Sorry for any confusion. I'm working on making a quick little program and proof for it now. I can't remember ever seeing multiplication this way!

Comment: @ElThor My mistake.  I need to take a closer look.

Comment: Apart from the switch of order, it is the standard recursive definition of multiplication.

Comment: Yeah, it's the switch that makes it non-obvious.  It's like counting the number of elements in a grid of $a$ rows of $b$ elements by using a spiral pattern to cross out each element.

Comment: I provided some code and am looking stuff up online! Thanks everyone, and thank you @Andre Nicolas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplication it is! We prove this by induction on $a$ and $b$.

- **Base:** $f(0,b)=0$ by definition and $f(a,0)=f(0,a-1)+0=0$
- **Induction hypothesis:** $\forall n<a$ and $\forall m<b$, $f(n,m)=f(m,n)=m\cdot n$
- **Induction step:** We must prove that $f(a,b)=f(b,a)=a\cdot b$. We have
  \begin{align}
  f(a,b)&=f(b,a-1)+b\\
  &=f(a-1,b-1)+a+b-1
  \end{align}
  But by induction hypothesis, we have $f(a-1,b-1)=(a-1)(b-1)$ and $f(a-1,b-1)=f(b-1,a-1)$. Then
  $$f(a,b)=(a-1)(b-1)+a+b-1=ab$$
  and
  \begin{align}
  f(b,a)&=f(b-1,a-1)+a+b-1\\
  &=f(a-1,b-1)+a+b-1\\
  &=f(a,b)
  \end{align}

In fact, we could restrict the induction hypothesis to only $a-1$ and $b-1$ instead of *all* integers smaller than $a$ and $b$.